# Awk subtract last element of 6th Column to each value in column 5

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I am trying to write a awk one liner that can subtract the last element of the 6th column to each value in column 5 for example

```
5/20/2013 1085.00 1062.25 1065.00 1083.50 -381.00 07 2013
5/21/2013 1098.25 1075.00 1080.00 1097.25 -381.00 07 2013
5/22/2013 1113.75 1089.50 1096.00 1113.25 -381.00 07 2013
5/23/2013 1165.75 1106.50 1111.00 1118.50 -381.00 07 2013
5/24/2013 1124.75 1090.25 1110.00 1095.25 -381.00 07 2013
5/28/2013 1147.50 1091.50 1094.00 1128.25 -381.00 07 2013
5/29/2013 1135.25 1119.25 1125.25 1128.75 -159.75 11 2013
5/30/2013 1133.25 1117.75 1128.25 1129.50 -159.75 11 2013
5/31/2013 1155.00 1129.00 1129.25 1144.50 -159.75 11 2013
6/3/2013 1171.50 1140.75 1141.25 1165.75 -159.75 11 2013
6/4/2013 1165.00 1144.25 1164.25 1156.25 -159.75 11 2013
```

I would want an output of

```
1243.25
1257
1273
1278.25
1255
1288
1288.5
1289.25
1304.25
1325.5
1316
```

Comment: in this case, substract 2013?

Comment: 'trying to write'? Please include your sample code, then we can help you understand the concept that is causing you a problem. Good luck.

Comment: I don't see how you're getting those outputs. The "last element of the 6th row" is 2013, taking the first row, the "value in column 5" is 1083.5, and subtracting them gives 929.5, not 1243.25.

Comment: @Kevin ummmm no 6th row is the one with -159.75

Comment: @user1440194 that is the last element in the sixth **column**, not row.

Comment: @user1440194 You seem to have your concept of "row" and "column" reversed. `-159.75` is the 6th *column* of the last *row*.

Comment: @Kevin my fault typo thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$5}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]-$6}' file
1243.25
1257
1273
1278.25
1255
1288
1288.5
1289.25
1304.25
1325.5
1316
```

Comment: This is interesting on my linux box this works perfectly but on my UNIX box it does not subtract the last value from the 6th column any idea why this would occur? I really need to run this on my UNIX machine

Comment: This script is POSIX compliant (using only basic awk language features) try on your Linux box using the -P or --posix option and see for yourself. Therefore the copy of the file on your UNIX box is not the same as the file on your Linux box, assuming the output on your UNIX box is subtracting 0 (i.e. just printing out the fifth column) then the file has trailing blank lines, if not then tell me what value is being subtracted, what is the output you are seeing?

Comment: The output from the UNIX box is subtracting zero however the file does not have any trailing blank lines, the file is located in the same place on my network. I also tried running sed '/^$/d' on the file first with no luck

Comment: Either your file is different in some way (do a hexdump on both systems and compare) or you have a completely broken version of awk? What system are you using? What version of awk do you have and what is the output when you run `awk 'END{print $6}' file`?

Comment: I am using Solaris (SunOS 5.1) , when I run awk to print the last value of the column I get nothing back just a blank line. I am really confused over this and cant figure out what is going on

Comment: Use this: `awk '{a[NR]=$5;x=$6}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]-x}' file` Posix says that in an ‘END’ action, ‘$NF’ (and presumably, ‘$1’) retain their value from the last record read, if no intervening ‘getline’ occurred. However, some implementations (such as Solaris 10 ‘/usr/bin/awk’, ‘nawk’, or Darwin ‘awk’) reset these variables. A workaround is to use an intermediate variable prior to the ‘END’ block. Ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Limitations-of-Usual-Tools.html#touch

Comment: @user1440194 you should not use the default awk on Solaris it is known to be very broken. Instead of using /usr/bin/awk use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

Answer (score 0):

reverse the file, find the 6th-column in the *first* row, do all the subtractions, then reverse the output

```
tac file | awk 'FNR==1{key=$6} {print $5-key}' | tac
```

I don't know if `tac` is available on Solaris...